# Newton's method for function $f(x)=1- e^{x}$

Tags: functions, roots, newton-raphson

I am trying to find a solution for Newton's method for this function, $f(x)=1- e^{x}$, and figuring out if it converges for every initial starting point.

Now, from my understanding, Newton's method is defined as:

$x_{n+1} = x_{n}-\frac {f(x_{n})}{f^1(x_{n}}$

and to check if a function converges for every $x$, we use the error formula (where $P$ is the root):

$|x_{n+1} - P| =|x_{n}-P|*|x_{n}-P|*\frac {f^2(x_{n})}{2f^1(x_{n})}$

Convergence will happen when $|x_{n}-P|*\frac {f^2(x_{n})}{2f^1(x_{n})} <1$

Now, calculating the first and second derivatives of $f(x)=1- e^{x}$ we obtain:

$f^1(x_{n})=-e^{x_{n}}$

$f^2(x_{n})=-e^{x_{n}}$

With all this information, I am a little confused how to find a solution to the function and to check if for every initial starting point there is convergence. Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: I hope you know what $P$ is in your problem. If you draw your function and are aware of the geometric idea of Newton's method, you will see that the algorithm convergences for any starting value.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f$ is concave, monotonic and it is easy to check that there is a solution, hence it is unique.

Note that $f'(x)<0$ for all $x$, hence the Newton iteration is well defined.

You can show that if you start at **any** $x_0$ then $x_1 \ge 0$.

You can show that if $x_n \ge 0$ then $0 \le x_{n+1} \le x_{n}$, so $x_n$ is a
non increasing sequence bounded below, hence has a limit $x^* \ge 0$.

Since $x_{n+1} = x_n - {f(x_n) \over f'(x_n)}$ and $x_n \to x^*$, then
this gives $x^* = x^* - {f(x^*) \over f'(x^*)}$, or $f(x^*) = 0$ (since
$f'(x^*) \neq 0$).

Since the solution is unique (because of monotonicity) we must have
$x_n \to 0$ for any starting point.

Comment: I think that $f'(x)<0$, right? Also, $x_1>0$. Do you agree?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: Thanks for catching that, I thought it was $1-e^{-x}$.